# Kafka ByteArray

Tags: arrays, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using Kafka to send produce and consume messages.

Producing is fine, working with a `<String, ByteArray>` producer.

When consuming, I'm using the code below (taken from an example) but I'm getting each record as being just 8 bytes (sample output beneath code).

Is there a way a consumer can simply take a whole message as a byte array?

Code:

```java
props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");
KafkaConsumer<String, byte[]> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, byte[]>(props);

consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));
int i = 0;

while (true) {
    ConsumerRecords<String, byte[]> records = consumer.poll(100);
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> record : records)
        System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s\n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
}
```

Output of System.out :

```
offset = 1773133, key = 105906453, value = [B@b8eff39
offset = 1773134, key = 105906453, value = [B@7bb1504
offset = 1773135, key = 105906453, value = [B@67b6c728
offset = 1773136, key = 105906453, value = [B@60b1f9c5
offset = 1773137, key = 105906177, value = [B@1cbab5dd
offset = 1773138, key = 105906177, value = [B@4376907b
offset = 1773139, key = 105906177, value = [B@122880ba
offset = 1773140, key = 105906177, value = [B@7db82ceb
offset = 1773141, key = 105906177, value = [B@34657adc
```

I'm not looking forward to having to assemble a load of these records to re-create a message as I believe I'm missing something and manual assembly may be error prone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should use

```
System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s\n", record.offset(), record.key(), java.util.Arrays.toString(record.value()));
```

rather than depending on plain array.toString (which gives you garbage instead of actual content). Arrays are probably coming properly, you just debug it wrong way.

Comment: Damned! I had my head so far up Kafka I missed this - but I'm still getting multiple chunks/offsets/whatever the name for each single message that my producer is producing.

Comment: Can't I simply have some kind of listener/loop that gets a single array of bytes for each message that's coming in?

Comment: It should be trivial to do yourself - just call your method for each element in the map. KafkaConsumer is still quite low level API, so you get called back in same batches data is appearing on actual protocol. If you want something which will abstract it away to single-callback per message, you should look into something like Samza (http://samza.apache.org/) or KafkaStreams (http://www.confluent.io/blog/introducing-kafka-streams-stream-processing-made-simple/)